# Does $f(x,x)=0 \: \forall\; x\in \mathbb{R} \: \implies f(x,y)= g(x,y)(x-y) $?

Tags: functions

I feel like the following results are obvious but I'm at a loss on how to prove them:

1. $f(x,x)=0  \:   \forall\;  x\in \mathbb{R} \: \implies f(x,y)= g(x,y)(x-y) $ for some g
2. $f(x,x)=1  \:   \forall\;  x\in \mathbb{R} \: \implies f(x,y)= \frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$ for some g

Also, if we have two functions $f_{1},f_{2}$ that satisfy no.2, can we say anything about $f_{1}(x,y)f_{2}(y,x)$?

Sorry if this question has been asked before or if the answer is too trivial for anybody to even consider asking.

Comment: I can prove $(1.)$. Just set $g = f(x,y)/(x-y)$ for $x \neq y$ then $f = (x-y)g$... I'll have to think about 2.

Comment: For $2$, setting $g(x) = f(x, x)$ works. So does setting $g(x) = k$ for any constant $k$. In short... are there any conditions on $f$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, to prove (1.) simply define $g(x,y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{x-y}$ for $x \neq y$ and $g(x,x)=0$. Then, by considering the two cases in which $g$ is defined, it is easy to see $f(x,y) = g(x,y)(x-y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

In contrast, I will now argue (2.) is false in the differentiable case. Let $f(x,y) = 1+x-y$. Observe $f(x,x)=1+x-x=1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose there exists $g(x)$ such that $f(x,y) = \frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$ it follows:
$$ 1+x-y = \frac{g(x)}{g(y)} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (1+x-y)g(y) = g(x)$$
taking the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ yields:
$$ g(y) = g'(x) $$
But, this is only possible if $g(x)=c$ since the only function of both $x$ and $y$ is the constant function. However, it is clear that the quotient of constant functions cannot hope to reproduce the given $f(x,y)= 1+x-y$.

Comment: That was the exact counter example I was going to use. +1

Comment: @CameronWilliams here's an ugly question, for which set of functions is (2.) true?

Comment: Actually I think you could argue it a little easier *without* appealing to differentiability. If it is true that $$1+x-y = \frac{g(x)}{g(y)}$$ for all $x,y\in \Bbb R$, then it holds for $y=0$ and $x$ arbitrary to give that $1+x = \dfrac{1}{g(0)}g(x).$ But for such $g$, $1+x-y\neq \dfrac{g(x)}{g(y)}$.

Comment: Very nice, I just love calculus a bit too much...

Comment: Haha so do I. As for your "bonus" question, I haven't any clue.